# Laravel - Error en Relaciones de Tabla Intermedia

Tags: mysql, laravel, relaciones

Tengo un proyecto en que parte de la siguiente estructura de Entidad/Relación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la relación que pone "1:M", sería "1:N".

A grandes rasgos, es como sigue:

Empleados <<==>> Departamentos

- Un empleado PERTENECE a un departamento.
- Un departamento CONTIENE uno o más empleados

Empleados <<==>> Proyectos

- Un empleado puede dirigir un determinado proyecto.
- Un proyecto es dirigido por un determinado empleado.
- Un o más empleados participan en uno o varios proyectos.
- Uno o varios proyectos son "participados" por uno o varios empleados.

De esta última relación de N:N (Muchos a Muchos), si no me equivoco, sale una tabla intermedia o pivote, ¿no?

Pues, tras realizar toda la configuración de migraciones, modelos, factories y DatabaseSeeder, es algo referido a esta tabla intermedia o pivote que me produce este error al ejecutar el comando `php artisan db:seed`:

---

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_ud5_relations`.`empleado_proyecto`, CONSTRAINT `empleado_proyecto_proyecto_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`proyecto_id`) REFERENCES `proyectos` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `empleado_proyecto` (`empleado_id`, `proyecto_id`) values (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 8), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 16), (1, 18), (1, 19), (1, 20), (1, 24), (1, 27), (1, 29), (1, 33), (1, 34), (1, 37), (1, 39))

at D:\inetpubapache-www__laravel-homestead-proyectos\laravel_ud5_relations\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {

> 664|             throw new QueryException(
>       665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>       666|             );
>       667|         }
>       668|

Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_ud5_relations`.`empleado_proyecto`, CONSTRAINT `empleado_proyecto_proyecto_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`proyecto_id`) REFERENCES `proyectos` (`id`))")
      D:\inetpubapache-www__laravel-homestead-proyectos\laravel_ud5_relations\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

2   PDOStatement::execute()
      D:\inetpubapache-www__laravel-homestead-proyectos\laravel_ud5_relations\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

---

Como digo, las migraciones se efectúan correctamente, también los factories se efectúan bien en todas las tablas salvo en la tabla intermedia dónde, a veces, llegan a insertarse unos cuantos registros hasta que sale este ERROR y, a veces, el ERROR se produce antes de que se haya insertado un solo y se queda la tabla vacía.

¿Cuál es la causa del ERROR?

Muestro a continuación todo el proceso llevado a cabo y los contenidos de los archivos que entran en juego.

Bueno, he creado la base de datos, creado las migraciones, los factories y configurado el DatabaseSeeder tal como se muestra a continuación.

Teniendo en cuenta que la tabla "departamentos" guarda una clave foránea dentro de la tabla "empleados", y la de "proyectos" puede depender, igualmente, de la de  "empleados", el orden que llevo a cabo para crear las migraciones a través de Artisan de Laravel es:

- primero, la migración para la tabla "departamentos":
  `php artisan make:migration CreateDepartamentosTable --create departamentos`
- segundo, la migración para la tabla "proyectos":
  `php artisan make:migration CreateProyectosTable --create proyectos`
- y tercero, la migración para la tabla "empleados":
  `php artisan make:migration CreateEmpleadosTable --create empleados`

Y estos son sus contenidos, tras definir los campos para cada una de las tablas:

[**2018_11_12_100121_create_departamentos_table.php**]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDepartamentosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departamentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('codigo')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('departamentos');
    }
}
```

[**2018_11_12_100214_create_proyectos_table**]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProyectosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('proyectos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            /*$table->string('nombre');*/
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('titulo');
            $table->date('fechainicio');
            $table->date('fechafin');
            $table->integer('horasestimadas');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('proyectos');
    }
}
```

[**2018_11_12_100444_create_empleados_table**]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEmpleadosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('apellido1');
            $table->string('apellido2');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('telefono');
            $table->integer('departamento_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            //Indicando que se añade una clave foránea referida
            //al campo 'id' de la otra tabla 'departamentos'
            $table->foreign('departamento_id')->references('id')->on('departamentos');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('empleados');
    }
}
```

Tras tener las tablas básicas, creo la migración de la tabla intermedia o pivote:

```
php artisan make:migration CreateEmpleadoProyectoTable --create empleado_proyecto
```

Y su contenido,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEmpleadoProyectoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleado_proyecto', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('empleado_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('proyecto_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('empleado_id')->references('id')->on('empleados');
            $table->foreign('proyecto_id')->references('id')->on('proyectos');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('empleado_proyecto');
    }
}
```

Por ahora, no ejecuto el comando para migrar a la base de datos. Espero a crear los modelos, las relaciones y configurar el DatabaseSeeder antes de lanzarlo.

Ahora, entonces, los modelos en los que se configuran las relaciones correspondientes:

[**Departamento**]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Empleado;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Departamento extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'codigo', 'nombre',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function empleados() {
        return $this->hasMany(Empleado::class);
    }
}
```

[**Proyecto**]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Empleado;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Proyecto extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'titulo', 'fechainicio', 'fechafin', 'horasestimadas',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function empleados() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Empleado::class);
    }
}
```

[**Empleado**]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Proyecto;
use App\Departamento;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empleado extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'email', 'telefono', 'departamento_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function departamento() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Departamento::class);
    }

    public function proyectos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Proyecto::class);
    }
}
```

Y los factories:

[**DepartamentoFactory**]

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Departamento::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        //sentence, para frases aleatorias  || mt_ran(2,4) para generar una sentencia con un núm. de 2 a 4 palabras
        'codigo' => $faker-unique()->uuid,
        'nombre' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(1,2)),
    ];
});
```

[**ProyectoFactory**]

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Proyecto::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        //sentence, para frases aleatorias  || mt_ran(2,4) para generar una sentencia con un núm. de 2 a 4 palabras
        //'nombre' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(1,2)),
        //      para sentencias únicas (no repetidas en cada vuelta)
        ////'nombre' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(1,2)),
        'nombre' => $faker->unique()->sentence(mt_rand(1,2)),
        'titulo' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(2,4)),
        ////'fechainicio' => $faker->dateTimeThisCentury->format('Y-m-d'),
        ////'fechafin' => $faker->dateTimeThisCentury->format('Y-m-d'),
        'fechainicio' => $faker->date,
        'fechafin' => $faker->date,
        'horasestimadas' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 200, $max = 500),
    ];
});
```

[**EmpleadooFactory**]

```
<?php

use App\Departamento;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Empleado::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    ////$departamentos = Departamento::all();
    /**
     * Mejor que la anterior, poner como sigue:
     * para que no se consulte y se cargue la lista de nuevo cada vez que se genere
     * una instancia de Curso, lo que causaría lentitud en el proceso, se puede poner
     * la variable a STATIC
     */
    //static $departamentos = Departamento::all();
    /**
     * y como a las variables STATIC no se les puede asignar, directamente, un valor,
     * se deberá codificar de esta forma:
     */
    static $departamentos;
    $departamentos = Departamento::all();

    return [
        'nombre' => $faker->firstName,
        'apellido1' => $faker->lastname,
        'apellido2' => $faker->lastname,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'telefono' => $faker->tollFreePhoneNumber,
        'departamento_id' => $departamentos->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

Por último, configuro el DatabaseSeeder para que se rellenen ,adecuadamente, las tablas con datos de prueba:

[**DatabaseSeeder**]

```
<?php

use App\Empleado;
use App\Proyecto;
use App\Departamento;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
//        $this->call(UsersSeeder::class);
        $num_departamentos_crear = 10;
        factory(Departamento::class, $num_departamentos_crear)->create();

        //cantidad MÁX proyectos
        $cantidadProyectos = 40;
        ////$proyectos = factory(Proyecto::class, $cantidadProyectos)->create();
        //Como es una variable que no se va a usar, se obvia
        factory(Proyecto::class, $cantidadProyectos)->create();

        //cantidad MÁX empleados
        $cantidadEmpleados = 40;
        $empleados = factory(Empleado::class, $cantidadEmpleados)->create()
            /*->each(function($curso) use ($proyectos) {
                $empleado->proyectos()
                    ->attach($proyectos->random(mt_rand(20, 30)));
            });*/
            /**
             * El bloque de código anterior tiene esta lectura como sigue:
             *      >> Por cada instancia de $empleado generada
             *      y usando la variable exterior $proyectos
             *      >> Obtener de entre 20 a 30 resultados aleatorios
             *          random(mt_rand(20, 30)
             *      de la lista de proyectos disponibles
             *          $proyectos
             *      por medio de la relación definida dentro del modelo Curso
             *          proyectos()
             *      para que sean registrados en el $empleado que se está creando
             */

            /**
             * en vez del bloque anterior, para mejorarlo y facilitar algo más el código,
             * se puede establecer, también, de esta forma, en la que se considera
             * una equivalencia entre la cantidad de proyectos disponibles (40)
             * y los IDs que cada proyecto poseerá en la tabla (que de manera
             * predeterminada, irán de 1 a 40).
             * La aleatoriedad de la elección vendrá dada gracias al empleo de
             *      array_rand()
             *          >> del rango obtenido, escoger 20 resultados que serán aleatorios
             */
            ->each(function($empleado) use ($cantidadProyectos) {
                $empleado->proyectos()
                    ->attach(array_rand(range(1, $cantidadProyectos), 20));
            });
    }
}
```

Finalmente, ya ejecuto por la consola, los siguientes comandos para crear las tablas con sus relaciones y para ingresar los datps aleatorios:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

Es al ejecutar el segundo comando que se produce el ERROR de integridad sobre la tabla pivote ya mencionado al principio de esta publicación.

¿Entonces, ¿alguien observa algo incorrecto que produjera este ERROR?
Gracias por las respuestas y posibles sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

según sugerencias que he llegado a conseguir por parte de otras personas, he entendido que el error se producía que, en cierto momento del inserto, el valor a insertar era un 0 (en la consulta SQL que se expone en el bloque del error, se ve que uno de las "values" a insertar es un 0) y ese valor era imposible que coincidiera con un ID existente de otra tabla como debía ser el caso. Por ello, el error de integridad.

insert into empleado_proyecto (empleado_id, proyecto_id) values (1, **0**), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 8), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 16), (1, 18), (1, 19), (1, 20), (1, 24), (1, 27), (1, 29), (1, 33), (1, 34), (1, 37), (1, 39))

¿Y cuál era la causa del error? El error se localiza, en el contenido del archivo "**DatabaseSeeder**" dentro de esto:

```
->attach(array_rand(range(1, $cantidadProyectos), 20));
```

Más, concretamente, a lo resultante de `array_rand()`.
Vamos a ver:

- Si $cantidadProyectos vale 40, `range(1, $cantidadProyectos)` devuelve un array cuyos valores contenidos en él van del 1 al 40, ambos incluidos.
- El array es pasado a `array_rand()`; esta función, a su vez, devuelve otro array obteniendo uno o más valores de forma aleatoria, en este caso, 20.
- Pero la cuestión es que no obtiene los valores de cada una de las dimensiones del array pasado sino sus índices; por ello, aleatoriamente, es posible que una de las dimensiones del array devuelto con `array_rand()` contenga un 0 como valor.
- Como ese array, con un 0, es pasado como comjunto de valores para ser insertado en una tabla de la base de datos, valor que tiene que estar relacionado con el ID de otra tabla, y al no existir un ID de valor 0, se produce el ERROR de integridad planteado.

Vale, pues tras encontrar una primera solución algo más trabajada, como era la de hacer una copia del array devuelto por `array_rand()` y sumarle 1 a cada uno de sus valores, he conseguido que me sugirieran otra solución más sencilla:

- sustituir esto

  array_rand(range(1, $cantidadProyectos), 20)
- por esto

  array_rand(array_flip(range(1, $cantidadProyectos)), 20)

Según parece, al usar `array_flip()`, te aseguras de usar el valor en el rango y no el valor en los índices iniciales. Y, con ello, me evito obtener un 0 como posible valor aleatorio que pasar al `attach()`.

Pues eso es todo. Esperando que le pueda servir a otra persona que se le plantee el mismo error. Saludos.